# Query runs faster without an index. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two tables. One of those tables has this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `object_master_70974_` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_object` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id_master` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id_slave` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id_field` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id_slave_field` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_object`    (`id_object`,`id_master`,`id_slave`,`id_field`,`id_slave_field`),
 KEY `id_object_2` (`id_object`,`id_master`,`id_field`,`id_slave_field`),
 KEY `id_object_3` (`id_object`,`id_slave`,`id_field`),
 KEY `id_object_4` (`id_object`,`id_slave_field`),
 KEY `id_object_5` (`id_object`,`id_master`,`id_slave`,`id_field`),
 KEY `id_object_6` (`id_object`,`id_master`,`id_slave`,`id_slave_field`),
 KEY `id_master` (`id_master`,`id_slave_field`),
 KEY `id_object_7` (`id_object`,`id_field`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17827 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see, there is an overlapping index `KEY id_object_5 (id_object,id_master,id_slave,id_field)` and there is no index that would cover these three fields: `id_object`, `id_master`, `id_field`. However, when I run these two queries:

```
SELECT f1.id 
FROM object_70974_ f1  
LEFT JOIN object_master_70974_ mss0 ON mss0.id_object IN (70974,71759)  
AND mss0.id_master = 71100 AND mss0.id_slave = 70912 AND mss0.id_field = f1.id
```

and

```
SELECT f1.id 
FROM object_70974_ f1  
LEFT JOIN object_master_70974_ mss0 ON mss0.id_object IN (70974,71759)  
AND mss0.id_master = 71100 AND mss0.id_field = f1.id
```

they both return the same number of rows (since in fact `id_slave` field does not really matter) - `3530`, however, the first query is slower than the second query by one second - 8 and 7 seconds respectively. So, I guess I have to ask two questions - 1) why does the second query run faster, even though it does not use index and 2) why does the first query run so slowly and why does not it use an index (obviously). In short, what the heck is going on?

**EDIT**

This is the result of `EXPLAIN` command (identical for both queries):

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "f1"    "index" \N  "attr_80420_"   "5" \N  "3340"  "Using index"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "mss0"  "ref"   "id_object,id_object_2,id_object_3,id_object_4,id_object_5,id_object_6,id_master,id_object_7"   "id_master" "4" "const" "3529"  "Using where"
```

**EDIT**

It's extremely interesting, because if I `DROP` `id_master` index (which for some strange reason is used by both queries), then it starts to use `id_object_5` index.

**EDIT**

And, yes, with `id_master` index being dropped, both queries start to run super-fast. So, I guess there is some trouble with optimizer.

**EDIT**

I even have a guess what trouble faces the optimizer - it may be incorrectly treats `id_slave_field` field name in the key, as if it were two fields instead - `id_slave` and `id_field`. In this case it becomes reasonable, why it firstly used this key in both queries.

**EDIT**

Schema of `object_70974_`

```
CREATE TABLE `object_70974_` (
   `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `id_inherit` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `id_obj` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `if_control` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `id_order` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `if_archive` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `id_group` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `if_hist` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `if_garbage` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `id_color` CHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL,
   `id_text` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `if_default` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `id_parent` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   .... a long list of other fields
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `id_order` (`id_order`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=3636 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Don't *guess* at the data access being used - use built in tools to have the server *tell* you how it's processing both queries. For [tag:mysql], I believe it's called [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: Explain shows that both queries use an index.

Comment: Also, if mysql is like most database systems, it can use any index where you're querying based on the leftmost n columns (n between 1 and number of columns in index) - so I'd expect `id_object_2` could be used for your second query

Comment: What is really strange because there is no overlapping index containing id_object,id_master, and id_field

Comment: Your query is a bit non-sensical because it would always return all the `f1.id` values.  Of course, there might be duplicates returned as well.  But are you sure these are your queries and you have no `where` clause?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff. I minimized it. In reality it has `GROUP_CONCAT` etc

Comment: I would post the result of EXPLAIN command in a minute. It is really interesting, since it shows that both queries use `id_master` key

Comment: Then post the something closer to the real query.  As that is a bit non-sensical.

Comment: @Frisbee. In the context of the question it does not really matter, it will just cram the initial sql queries with rubbish.

Comment: 8 versus 7 is not much of a difference.  It does not know mss0.id_slave = 70912 does not make a difference so it has to check.  Why are you optimizing something with no real meat?

Comment: What do you mean by "8 versus 7" and "no real meat"?

Comment: It's a real world query which looks seven times uglier, but is minimized just for the purposes of the question.

Comment: 8 is is like 14% different than 7.  No meat in that is just returns all f1.ID plus possible dubs.  Why in the id_field is a bigint and id and int - mss0.id_field = f1.id.

Comment: "and int - mss0.id_field = f1.id." . Please, pay attention, that it is not `int`, They are both `bigint`'s. And as for the query, as I said it has 100% of sense in it. But it does not matter in the context of the question (to post all GROUP_CONCAT and blablabla, however, would have no sense at all)

Comment: "`id` int(10)" - is part of  `object_master_70974_`. Whereas, `f1.id` is part of `object_70974_ f1`. So, pay attention to details and do not be rude, even if you do not understand something.

Comment: And where is the `CREATE TABLE object_70974_` so we can see that it is `BIGINT`?

Comment: Here it is. Just wait one second.

Answer (score 1):

Why does the `SELECT` mention f1 at all?  It is essentially useless.  This would give the same answer, possibly except for some end case:

```
SELECT  mss0.id_field
    FROM  object_master_70974_ mss0
    WHERE  mss0.id_object IN (70974, 71759)
      AND  mss0.id_master = 71100
      AND  mss0.id_slave = 70912
```

The optimal index for that is

```
INDEX(id_master, id_slave, id_object)
```

where master and slave can be in either order, but `id_object` is *last*.  Build the 'best' index by *starting* with any `WHERE` clause that have `= (constant)`.

Don't use `LEFT` unless you are want to see `NULLs` for the 'right' table when there is no match.  I think this is part of the problem -- the optimizer was forced to start with `f1` when it would be a lot better to start with the other table.

8 vs 7 seconds could be caching.

Note in the `EXPLAIN` that it needs to hit 3K rows in each table.

Comment: That is totally incorrect. If you look closer, then you will see, that I'm using `LEFT JOIN` and `SELECT` from two tables. The result of your query will be completely different from mine.

Comment: As for `f1`, as I said multiple times, this query is a part of a larger and real one, where `f1` is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Then perhaps the best index would be `INDEX(id_master, id_slave, id_field, id_object)`.  `id_object` last; the rest in any order.

Comment: And can you, please, explain why the order of fields does not matter. I always though that it really matters. Probably, you have some reference to documentation. I ask this question, because I though that in my query (the first one), it should be like `INDEX (id_object, id_master, id_slave, id_field)`

Comment: I'd better ask, why `id_object` should not come first in the index.

Comment: `= constant` items in `WHERE` should be put first.  Otherwise the lookup needs to jump around, sometimes to the point of giving up and not using the rest of the index, or not using the index at all.  See `Key_len` in `EXPLAIN`; it sometimes gives a clue.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` gives more clues.

Comment: The order among multiple `=const` does not matter because it is simply drilling down a BTree.  (OK, I'm not explaining it very well.)

Comment: Once you hit a "range" (>, BETWEEN, ...), nothing more in the index can be used.  `IN(const, const)` is somewhere between `=const` and a 'range' in what the optimizer can do with it.